# Grant site permission based on the total accumulated, rather than current, reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties, tag-creation

I've been using Stack Exchange sites for about seven years now, and in that time I've probably accumulated a few thousand reputation points — primarily on Stack Overflow. Recently I was posting a new question regarding the Swift AWS Lambda Runtime. The runtime hasn't gotten that much attention due to AWS developers choosing more established runtimes over it to build their Lambdas; namely, Python, Java, or Node.js. But it is rising in popularity, but apparently not enough to merit its own tag. So I commenced to add it myself, but couldn't because I didn't have the prerequisite 1500 reputation points.

I think this is a little misguided, as I feel reputation points here are being used as a measure of trustworthiness. But at the same time I feel that the majority of Stack Overflow users are on there to get answers, not answer questions; maybe I'm wrong. But if not, then it's plausible that many other users may be in my shoes where their reputation points are below a given prerequisite amount not as a consequence of insufficient contributions to the site or being penalized, but because of the tendency to issue bounties when posting relatively difficult questions; if you're mainly *asking* questions here, then statistically, it's really only a matter of time before you ask some difficult enough to warrant posting a bounty to inspire answers.

Ask enough of them and post enough bounties, and your reputation points will no longer be an accurate measure of your trustworthiness. And if the majority falls into this demographic, then the majority of users have reputation points that are not reflections of their trustworthiness, and therefore will be restricted from interacting with the sites in ways someone with their experience otherwise would be enabled to.

One approach to this problem would be instead of granting permissions to users based on how many reputation points they currently have, base it on their *total* accumulated reputation points. This may be undesirable for some permissions, but for something like creating new question tags, I think it's progress towards a more accurate reputation system.

Comment: Stack Overflow is the largest site by far and because of that a large number of bad tags are created even with the requirement set that high. On nearly all other sites tag creation requires 300 rep.

Comment: [Related request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268808/make-basic-informational-privileges-network-wide) which is more popular because it does not ask for moderation privileges like this request. If you happen to have e.g. 300 rep on some random SE site (or even 300000), it should not let you create tags on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar I thought it might have been about network wide reputation initially but it seems to be more about still counting rep from all the bounties you've created on the one site.

Comment: @RobertLongson so I'm voting to close this as unclear.

Comment: Absolutely not. This would overwhelm the smaller sites with ignorant users from the larger ones.

Comment: Re (my emphasis) *"...on how many* ***reputation points*** *they currently have, base it on their* ***total accumulated reputation"***:  It is not clear what the difference is between the two. Presumably minus reputation points "lost" to bounties. Perhaps *"...on how many reputation points they currently have, base it on their vote total"*

Answer (score 3):

Bounties are supposed to sting a bit, that keeps them rare and if they are rare you're more likely to get the result you want.

If there's a significantly reduced penalty at all for bounties then you could just keep creating them which would mean lots more of them. Those people that are influenced to look for bountied questions to answer would have lots more bountied questions to choose from resulting in them being less likely to see your question.

Note that tag creation on Stack Overflow is special because of its size, normally its 300 rep but even with 1500 rep as a minimum Stack Overflow still has to deal with a significant number of bad tags.

There is a way round it though, if you want a tag created ask a question on [Stack Overflow's Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) be sure to provide one or more questions that could be tagged and the tag wiki information you think would be appropriate. For more information see [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work) specifically the part about

> If you do not have enough reputation to create the tag...

Comment: You are only guessing question is about bounties and not network wide reputation, high risk you missed the actual question.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Well it doesn't mention network reputation and it does mention bounties so i'm answering based on what's actually in the question.

Comment: "I've been using Stack Exchange sites for about seven years now, and in that time I've probably accumulated a few thousand reputation points — **primarily** on StackOverflow" - the use of "primarily" means the OP is talking about the overall reputation, as far as I can tell. But again, we're both just guessing here. Question is indeed just not clear, and only the one who wrote it can explain the true meaning.

Comment: I've got 100k on Super User and Meta. I know less about most of the topics on SE than the average pug.  Network wide reputation shouldn't count for much outside the association bonus IMO

Comment: The question is quite clear, particularly when you read it with the context given by its title in mind; +1 for a considered rebuttal, even if I don't *entirely* agree with you as using gross, rather than net of bounties, reputation in some circumstances might be a good way to reward a user who rewards other users for answering questions. Maybe.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar He is not guessing. He understood the question exactly as it was intended; as did Rob.

Comment: "If there's a significantly reduced penalty for bounties then you could just keep creating them which would mean lots more of them." Well you wouldn't exactly be able to just keep creating them — you'd be limited by how many reputation points you currently have. And if the majority of users sit from 100 to 2000 points on _any given site_, and a bounty needs to be 200 or more to inspire answers, then they may only be able to post on average 5 bounties before their points dip so low that they can't anymore.

Comment: Furthermore, if these same people are primarily here for asking questions, then it will take them a considerably long time to regain those lost reputation points. In my experience with StackOverflow in particular, I find the quality of questions you write and the likelihood that you'll post at all are inversely proportional; as the skills you garner from writing better and better questions aids you in solving your own questions before resorting to posting.

Comment: Which increases the bar for posting, increasing the likelihood that the few questions _you do_ post will be difficult, and therefore the likelihood that they'll merit bounties to inspire the effort to answer them. Increasing the likelihood for you to lose your reputation points and loose privileges that would otherwise enable you to contribute to the site in a positive way.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I feel that the current policy disproportionately impacts experienced, trustworthy users who are here for getting answers, not necessarily providing them, and that there may be enough of these users to warrant changing the policy. And also, that a policy change wouldn't necessarily have to come with prohibitive downsides.